# How can I find a tuple from a group of tuples with the values closest to a given tuple?

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I'm working with python and have a dict where the keys are tuples with 3 values each.

I'm computing another tuple with 3 values, and I want to find the tuple in the keys of the dict with the closest values to this newly computed tuple.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Add a sample case http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: @Divakar I'll have to ask again later then, I'm on mobile, don't have the code in front of me

Comment: You need to define the meaning of "closest"

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the `abs()` of the difference, e.g.:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> d = [tuple(randint(1, 20) for _ in range(3)) for _ in range(5)]
>>> d
[(4, 13, 10), (12, 18, 19), (11, 18, 8), (16, 17, 4), (2, 4, 10)]
>>> k = tuple(randint(1, 20) for _ in range(3))
>>> k
(14, 13, 1)
>>> min(d, key=lambda x: sum(abs(m-n) for m, n in zip(k, x)))
(16, 17, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def euclid2(x,y):
    return sum((xi-yi)**2 for xi,yi in zip(x,y))

def closestTuple(target,tuples, dist = euclid2):
    return min((dist(t,target),t) for t in tuples)[1]

#test:
target = (3,5,1)
tuples = [(3,1,2), (4,1,5), (6,1,7), (4,4,2), (1,5,7)]
print(closestTuple(target,tuples)) #prints (4,4,2)
```

This finds the tuple which is closest to the target tuple in the Euclidean metric. You could of course pass another function for the `dist` parameter.

Comment: Using `functools.partial` you can do this using the `key`, e.g. `return min(t, key=functools.partial(dist, target))` or alternatively use a lambda, `key=lambda x: dist(x, target)`.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for the suggestion. `functools` is one of the modules that I should probably explore some more. It is a matter of taste, but I find the 1-line definition without `functools` slightly more readable than the 1-line definition with `functools`. Your solution for the taxicab metric with passing `min` a `key` is nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (i used a list), and simply iterate over each element, and take the difference between each element in the tuple, then in the end sort the sums of the differences and look for the smallest amount

```
a = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7)]
b = (2, 4, 5)
c = []
for x in a:
     c[a.index(x)] = 0
     for i in range(len(x)):
            c[i]+=x[i]-b[i]
```